# How to connect MS SSMS Express to server (Integrated Security)

Tags: ssms, integrated-security

I'm trying to connect via SSMS to our MS SQL Server 2005.
I first tried to connect via visual studio programmatically.
It worked after I found out that I have to put "Integrated Security=SSPI;" into the connection string, otherwise it refused the connection with a "login failed" error.

Now Im trying to connect via the SSMS but now I get also a refuse when I try to connect.
Sadly there is no option where I can set "Integrated Security=SSPI" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the "Windows Authentication" option in the Connection Dialog for SSMS is equivalent to putting "Integrated Security=SSPI" in the connection string.

[image]

This will use the credentials of the SSMS process when connecting to the server.

As a note you can also achieve this same result by using the "Additional Connection Parameters" text box. Click on the "Options >>" button at the bottom of the Connection Dialog and select the "Additional Connection Parameters" tab.

[image]

Then enter in the text "Integrated Security=SSPI" (without quotes) into the text box. This will override whatever the Authentication option chosen in the drop-down menu is.

More information can be found [in the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186481.aspx) or by pressing F1 when the Connection Dialog has focus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Im using Express Version 2005, where is no "Additional Connection Parameters" and Im not able to use Windows Auth, as I have to use other credentials.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Have you tried using SSMS 2012? It is backwards compatible with SQL 2005. You can download it here: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Choose either SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe or SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe based on your architecture.